# Spring Boot - How to secured the dashboards like Hystrix for admin users

Tags: spring-boot, hystrix

I have spring boot REST service with a basic authentication already existing. I have Hystrix integrated to short circuit external services and a dashboard to monitor the same. But how to secure Hystrix dashboard for an admin user?

Thanks,
Arun.

Answer (score 0):

Configure Spring Security to enforce basic auth on `/hystrix` endpoint. For example:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/hystrix")
            .authenticated();    
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added this already. It works with the url localhost:8080/hystrix when I provide the credentials. But it is also authenticating once I enter '/hystrix.stream' and hit 'Monitor'. Basically it authenticates for all the request (AJAX calls) made within the dashboard screen on refresh where I am not able to provide the cred. My service is STATELESS.

Comment: This authenticates only "/hystrix". Stream endpoint does not require authentication if you configure security like that.

Comment: It doesn't work with the below security configuration. .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)